# How can I get deviation scores to sum to zero in R?

Tags: r, sum

I have a vector of data and I want to 'manually' calculate variance and standard deviation.

```
pointsPerGame<-c(28,26,10,27,20,38,23,28,25,2)
```

I can get the deviation scores like this

```
pointsPerGame - mean(pointsPerGame)
```

But when I try to get the sum of the deviation scores it won't sum to zero like it should.

```
deviationScores<- pointsPerGame - mean(pointsPerGame)
sum(deviationScores)
```

I know this has to do with the level of precision in R, but I don't know how to prevent it from doing so for my purposes.

Hope you can help.

This question has been flagged as an answer to my question [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)
But I want R to display 0 for teaching purposes, it'd be extremely confusing to get into the details of floating points etc.

Comment: The answer is in your question already.

Comment: @PierreLafortune but I get a value of 7.105427e-15

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You figured out the answer already; you just have to accept that you are an analyst and a part-time computer scientist now. Floating point arithmetic is with you unless you prefer the allure of Excel.

```
all.equal(0L, sum(deviationScores))
[1] TRUE
```

**Edit**

For teaching purposes, to show `0` for the sum.

```
devsum <- sum(deviationScores)
devsum <- if(all.equal(0L, devsum)) 0L else devsum
```

Comment: thanks for the response but if, for the purposes of teaching, I want it to show 0, how can this be done?

Comment: Teaching script added.